# 11 Added photo: In our 1959 ranch-style home there is an outlet on a living room wall

Tags: electrical

11

Adding photo to previous:[1959 home outlet in wall]
In our 1959 ranch-style home there is an outlet on a living room wall more than halfway up. Anyone know for what use this may have been installed? It looks built-in when the house was built.

Comment: Please **edit your original question** to add the picture. Use the "sun and mountains" icon along the top of the edit box to add the picture. Whatever your tried here didn't work (don't fiddle with what the picture adding code puts in or it can break the picture link.)

Comment: wall-mount fan, or electric clock perhaps?